# Does CORS mean you will no longer see a same-origin policy error in the console?

Tags: javascript, ajax, http, cross-domain, cors

Sorry if this sounds really stupid, but I'm just trying to get my head straight with cross-domain requests and the new CORS specification.

I remember a few years ago, seeing errors in the javascript console when I would try to make a cross-origin request via ajax that included the `x-requesed-with` header (which would make it a non-simple GET, HEAD, or POST request). Chrome would simply tell me I couldn't make the request because of the same-origin policy.

Now that we have CORS I assume that instead of an error, Chrome will simply initiate the preflight `OPTIONS` request with the `x-requested-with` header listed in the `access-control-request-headers` preflight header. Is my understanding of CORS accurate? Will I no longer see cross-origin errors unless the preflight does not return an `access-control-allow-origin` header?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not. You have to configure the server to send out the proper allow headers. If it does not, the browser will display the same error you mentioned.

You have to allow origin, methods, headers, etc... Why don't you read the [standard](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/) or the [mozilla description](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS)?! Both are pretty short texts, just a few pages...

Comment: Right. I know the server needs to be configured to respond with the proper CORS headers. I have read the spec, a few articles, and I'm reading about CORS in ng-book. This question was just a sanity check about the way the browser behaves compared to how it used to behave pre-CORS. Instead of a "same-origin policy" error the browser now has a "no access-control-allow-origin header present" error after the initial preflight request comes back, it would seem. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: np :-) Btw it is an interesting topic from a security aspect, by non GET and POST requests the browser sends out an OPTIONS preflight at first, and if it does not get the right answer it won't send the request. It is nice to mention, that according to SOP, it does send the POST request, but it does not show the response, so it does not protect you for example against CSRF. You need to add XSS protection and/or content security policy headers to do that.